# Issue with using AJAX to send an JSON Array to a PHP file

Tags: ajax, json, post

Hi I'm new to using ajax and json so I've made the sample code below to try it out before using it for my project but I've run into some problems when I try to send information to my PHP file. I've formatted the input so it's in JSON format and got the Ajax command, as far as I know, working correctly.
But when I was running the code I was looking at what I posted using FireBug and it says the values of the input I'm sending to the PHP are undefined. I'm not sure why this happens since I got it to work with a single input. I've also tried using json.stringify in my HTML code then json_decoding it in the PHP file as a work around but I couldn't get it to work for the single input case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
 var sendInput = [
                {"fruit":"apple", "amount":"5"},
                {"fruit":"pear", "amount":"15"}];
   var sent = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: sendInput,
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "AjaxTest.php",
        success: function(data) {
            window.alert(data);
                window.alert("Works");
        },
        error: function() {
            window.alert("Failed");
        }
    });
```

PHP:
nothing special right now it just echos any value in $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax expects data attribute to be either a string or a plain object. But you have defined an array. If that's what you want to send, try something like below:

```
var sendInput = {"myinput":[
            {"fruit":"apple", "amount":"5"},
            {"fruit":"pear", "amount":"15"}]};
```

Comment: Hey I've tried what you've suggested but now when I check what it sends using firebug now it says that I'm sending an array of objects, this is what firebug gives me,
inputarray [object Object]
inputarray [object Object]
Do you know how I would decode it to get the values back or how I would index it in the php?